# Копирование Объектов класса

Tags: c++, классы

у меня есть вопрос. Можно ли обычно присвоить объект одного класса другому объекту того же типа. Например

```
class Type
{
   public : 
   int value;    
};
 int main()
{
 Type a;
 Type b;
 a=b;
}
```

Проблема в том что рекомендуют делать определенную процедуру. Однако что произойдет если сделать иначе?

Comment: "...рекомендуют делать определенную процедуру". Это где рекомендуют? Наоборот, рекомендуется составлять классы так, чтобы никаких дополнительных "процедур" не нужно было делать, т.е. чтобы неявно сгенерированное компилятором копирование правильно решало задачу.

Comment: в книге Аллекс Эллайн. Там просто упоминалось об Операторе присваивания и Конструкторе копирования

Comment: точнее будет если я скажу не процедура а метод

Comment: Вероятно имелось ввиду написание собственной операции для присваивания, в случае, если в полях используются указатели. Т.к. компилятор просто скопирует их, в результате чего оба объекта будут  иметь указатель на один и тот же адрес.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не напишете свой оператор присваивания, компилятор сгенерирует таковой сам. В таком простом классе, как у вас, этого вполне достаточно - сгенерированный оператор будет просто копировать все почленно, опять же используя либо имеющиеся операторы, либо генерируя их самостоятельно.

Answer (score -1):

Если ничего не выделять, в куче вполне достаточно оператора присваивания, генерируемого по умолчанию.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Не согласен с вами, тут надо смотреть на спецификацию класса. Например, если у объекта класса есть уникальный номер, то оператор присваивания по умолчанию не подойдет, хотя тут кучу мы не трогаем.